I need to filter out `grep`'s output to find a device's serial number, in order to store it into a variable
I'm working on a section of a script that will find the serial number of a Mac, store it into a variable and rename the device according to the naming standards of my workplace. So far, I have the following:
% system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep Serial
      Serial Number (system): [serial number]

I want to be able to filter this output even more, so I can store the serial number as its own variable.
Any ideas on how I can do this?

Is the serial number only numerical or can it contain letters or dashes or any other kind of character? Is it really surrounded by [ ] or is that only for the question?

You could use sed instead of grep:
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | sed -n 's/.*Serial Number (system): //p'

.*Serial Number (system):  is a "safe" pattern which will match the target line until right before the serial number starts, regardless of the contents of the serial number itself; I'm being this pedantic about matching the section of the line to be removed because it's unclear to me whether older machines's serial number could contain characters outside of the subset of [A-Z0-9] they use today (all I know is they changed their serial number's format a few years back).
If you're going to use this on "recent" machines, where the serial number is positively going to be a subset of [A-Z0-9], then it's safe to greedily match everything up until the last space, and the sed command could be shorted to:
sed -n 's/.*Serial.* //p'

The -n option will turn off output for all lines, while the p flag will override this and print the result of the substitution in case a substitution of the pattern has taken place.
As to how to store the output into a variable, you could place the command into a command substitution:
serial=$(system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | sed -n 's/.*Serial Number (system): //p')


Using pcregrep (not included in macOS but installable via Homebrew), you could do:
pcregrep -o '.*Serial Number \(system\): \K.*'

Which will print only what has been matched after \K; you'll need to use pcregrep instead of grep because unlike GNU grep, BSD grep doesn't have built-in support for PCREs (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions), and \K is a PCRE feature that requires PCRE support in order to work.

Since the OP seems to be happy matching just Serial, I don't think it's worth complicating the answer by trying to match more.

The sed call can be shortened by removing the neet to capture anything: sed -n 's/.*Serial Number (system): //p'. If the user is happy to just look for the word Serial: sed -n '/Serial/ s/.*: //p' or sed -e '/Serial/!d' -e 's/.*: //'

@terdon The serial number's format should be standard and a subset of [A-Z0-9] for more "recent" machines, however I'm unsure if older machines' serial numbers could contain spaces / other stuff. So for the general answer (which I'd like to be useful to anyone, not just OP) I'd like to stay on the safe side and to make sure to stop where I positively won't eat a section of the serial. However it's fair enough to state that on all newer machines .*Serial.*  will be enough, so I pointed out why I'm being so pedantic about the pattern I and added a shorter version, thanks.

@Kusalananda I'd like to stay on the safer side of things because of the reasons I explained to terdon; however your first suggestion is 100% sensible, there's absolutely no need to replace anything, so I changed that bit. Thanks

If your output really is like what you show, and assuming the serial number itself is i) always the last whitespace-separated string on the line and ii) there is only one line matching Serial, you could just use awk:
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Serial/{print $NF}'

That awk command will print the last field (NF is the number of fields, and $NF is the content of the last field) on any lines matching the string Serial.

Looking at the output of the command online, it seems like there's always goingo to be a single "Serial" line, and that, at least on newer machines, the last space-separated field will always contain the full serial
